# SharePoint 2010 Server Configuration Error -> "Cannot connect to database master"

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sharepoint, installation

I recieve the following error when I try to configure SharePoint 2010 Server:

"Cannot connect to the database master at SQL server at [computer.domain]. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it."

*I run the following setup:*

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with SP1 and all the updates
- SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1
- SharePoint Server 2010 with SP1
- Everything is installed on the same server (it's a testserver)

*I have tried the following:*

- Rebooting the server
- Checking the install account's DB rights (dbcreator, securityadmin - I even let it have sysadmin)
- Opened up the firewall on port 1433 and 1434
- Uninstalled both SQL and SP, then reinstalled the both
- Enabled all client protocols in SQL Server Configuration
- Made sure I used the correct account for installing SharePoint (local admin)

Useful links:
TCP/IP settings –> http:// blog.vanmeeuwen-online.nl/2010/10/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at.html

http:// ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-sql2008r2/

Wrong slash  ->  http:// yakimadev.com/2010/11/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-serverdbname-error-during-sharepoint-2010-products-configuration-wizard-and-installation/

Port error  ->  http:// www.knowsharepoint.com/2011/08/error-connecting-to-database-server.html

Comment: Hello! Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but, check the binding for your portal site in IIS.  Click the "edit" button and make sure a certificate is chosen for your ssl binding. If there is no certificate (or it "came loose" somehow), you won't be able to access the site at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the configuration wizard failing with a database connection error.

Comment: I beg to differ.  Would you like to say why you think that?

Comment: Because note being able to access the site (which may or may not be caused by a SSL issue) is a problem that could happen *after* running the Product Configuration Wizard; if the wizard itself fails, the problem is much more serious and the site hasn't even been brought online.

Comment: Ah you may be right actually; but I do know that if your SSL certificate is out of whack that in SCA you may be able to access a page but the controls and wizards may yet fail.  I've experienced this myself.

Comment: He was referring to the *initial* wizard, the one which creates the farm and the SCA website.